# Rust error when using sort with seq::index::sample

Tags: sorting, random, rust, sample

So I was trying to generate a sample of 5 numbers with:

```
use rand::{thread_rng, seq};
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main(){
    let mut rng = thread_rng();

    let mut sample = seq::index::sample(&mut rng, 50, 5);
}
```

But when I try to sort it with:

```
sample.sort();
```

It gives me the following error:

> error[E0599]: no method named `sort` found for type
>   `rand::seq::index::IndexVec` in the current scope   -->
>   src/main.rs:12:16

How can I sort a random sample of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rand::seq::index::sample`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/seq/index/fn.sample.html) returns an [`rand::seq::index::IndexVec`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/seq/index/enum.IndexVec.html) rather than a regular `Vec`. This type seems to be mostly intended to be iterated and does not have many methods. In particular, it has no `sort` method.

You can use [`into_vec`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/seq/index/enum.IndexVec.html#method.into_vec) to get a normal `Vec`, which is `sort`able.